# How do I chain adapter calls from the mobile client in Worklight 6.2?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

Can someone explain how you chain adapter calls using Worklight 6.2?

I am currently developing a hybrid mobile application using Worklight and the issue I have is that I need to make *x* number of calls to a specific Worklight adapter, the last call in the stack will always be to a different Worklight adapter. Each adapter call needs to wait for the result of the previous call before being initiated.

I'm able put all of the calls into a stack, and call each one in turn, but they don't appear to wait for the previous one to finish before the next one starts?

The code I have at the moment is as follows:

```
// Following line is executed in a loop to build the call stack
defCollection.push(sendUpdate(data));


// Following code executes the call stack
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

$.each(defCollection, function(index, sndUpd) {
    WL.Logger.info("EXECUTING :: " + index);
    promise = promise.pipe(function() {return sndUpd;});
});

deferred.resolve();


// This is the Worklight adapter call
function sendUpdate(data){
    var params = data;

    var invocationData = {
        adapter : "live",
        procedure : "update",
        parameters : [params],
        compressResponse : true
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : updateSuccess,
        onFailure : updateFailure
    });
}
```

I know that .pipe is deprecated, but for the moment, this is the closest I have managed to come in getting the calls to execute in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

By using `defCollection.push(sendUpdate(data));` you executing the `sendUpdate` function and passing it's response "output" to `defCollection.push()`.

Try using `defCollection.push(sendUpdate)` and then calling `promise = promise.then(function() {return sndUpd(yourDataObjectHere);});`

So your code should look like:

```
var youDataCollectionArray = [];
youDataCollectionArray.push(data);


defCollection.push(sendUpdate);


// Following code executes the call stack
var deferred = $.Deferred();
var promise = deferred.promise();

$.each(defCollection, function(index, sndUpd) {
    WL.Logger.info("EXECUTING :: " + index);
    promise = promise.then(function() {return sndUpd(youDataCollectionArray[index]);});
});

deferred.resolve();


// This is the Worklight adapter call
function sendUpdate(data){
    var params = data;

    var invocationData = {
        adapter : "live",
        procedure : "update",
        parameters : [params],
        compressResponse : true
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : updateSuccess,
        onFailure : updateFailure
    });
}
```

Where `youDataCollectionArray` is an array of parameters that you will pass to your functions. In this case `youDataCollectionArray` and `defCollection` should be the same length

**UPDATE:**

`WL.Client.invokeProcedure` supports promises so this will be my recommended way of handling your code

```
sendUpdate(data).then(function(response){

  return sendUpdate(otherData);
}).then(function(response){

  /*
   * this will be similar to sendUpdate but it will call different adapter
   * since you said the call last call will be to a different adapter.
   */
  return lastAdapterInvocation();
}).then(function(response){
  // last's adapter success
}).fail(function(errorResponse){
  // Failed to invoke adapter
});


function sendUpdate(data){
  var params = data;

  var invocationData = {
    adapter : "live",
    procedure : "update",
    parameters : [params],
    compressResponse : true
  };

  return WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData);
}
```

In this example you will be calling `sendUpdate` twice and `lastAdapterInvocation` after the second `sendUpdate` finishes. `lastAdapterInvocation` will invoke the adapter you mentioned that needs to be called at last, you will need to implement that function the same way `sendUpdate` is implemented.

Remember that you can chain more calls to `sendUpdate` in the middle if you wish.

Comment: Hi Yoel, thanks for the fast reply. I've tried your suggestion, the calls are executed in the right order, but they still don't wait for the response from the previous call before the next one is executed? Do you have any further ideas?

Comment: Hi @ChrisP I added an update to my answer to demonstrate the use of promises